# Split string into class

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have an array which contains following values:

```
str[0]= "MeterNr 29202"
str[1]="- 20111101: position 61699 (Previous calculation) "
str[2]="- 20111201: position 68590 (Calculation) consumption 6891 kWh"
str[3]="- 20111101: position 75019 (Previous calculation) "
str[4]="MeterNr 50273"
str[5]="- 20111101: position 18103 (Previous reading) "
str[6]="- 20111201: position 19072 (Calculation) consumption 969 kWh "
```

I want to split the rows in logical order so that I can store them in following Reading class. I have problems with spliting the values. Everything in brackets () is ItemDescription.

I will be thankful for the quick answer.

```
public class Reading
{
    public string MeterNr { get; set; }

    public string ItemDescription { get; set; }

    public string Date { get; set; }

    public string Position { get; set; }

    public string Consumption { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific? How should the output look like? In other words, what should return MeterNr, ItemDescription, etc.

Comment: There are several options. One is to check(IndexOf) for the starting ( and for the ending ) and take what's inside. Or you can do that using a regular expression.

Comment: Try describing in english (or your language of choice) exactly what you want out of each line, that should give you a hint as to what you should do. Further hint: it doesn't seem that you *need* regex, a simple IndexOf/substring can already help.

Comment: @all above: Sample output for str[2]: MeterNr=29202, Description= Calculation, Date=20111201, Position=68590, Consumption= 6891 kWh

Comment: and after str[4] MeterNr changes to 50273, right? Then is this used also in str[5] and str[6]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use a for loop and string indexes etc, but then I am a bit simple like that!  Not sure of your data (i.e. if things might be missing) but this would work on the data you have posted...

```
var readings = new List<Reading>();
int meterNrLength = "MeterNr".Length;
int positionLength = "position".Length;
int consumptionLength = "consumption".Length;
string meterNr = null;

foreach(var s in str)
{
    int meterNrIndex = s.IndexOf("MeterNr",
                                 StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    if (meterNrIndex != -1)
    {
        meterNr = s.Substring(meterNrIndex + meterNrLength).Trim();
        continue;
    }

    var reading = new Reading {MeterNr = meterNr};

    string rest = s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf(':'));
    reading.Date = rest.Substring(1).Trim();

    rest = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("position") + positionLength);

    int bracketIndex = rest.IndexOf('(');

    reading.Position = rest.Substring(0, bracketIndex).Trim();

    rest = rest.Substring(bracketIndex + 1);

    reading.ItemDescription = rest.Substring(0, rest.IndexOf(")"));

    int consumptionIndex = rest.IndexOf("consumption",
                                        StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    if (consumptionIndex != -1)
    {
        reading.Consumption = rest.Substring(consumptionIndex + consumptionLength).Trim();
    }

    readings.Add(reading);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should parse the values one by one.
If you have a string, which starts with "MeterNr", you should save it as `currentMeterNumber` and parse the values further.
Otherwise, you can parse the values with Regex:

```
var dateRegex = new Regex(@"(?<=-\s)(?<year>\d{4})(?<month>\d{2})(?<day>\d{2})");
var positionRegex = new Regex(@"(?<=position\s+)(\d+)");
var descriptionRegex = new Regex(@"(?<=\()(?<description>[^)]+)(?=\))");
var consuptionRegex = new Regex(@"(?<=consumption\s+)(?<consumption>(?<consumtionValue>\d+)\s(?<consumptionUom>\w+))");
```

I hope, you would be able to create the final algorithm, as well as understand how each of those expressions works. A final point could be to combine them all into single Regex. You should do it yourself to enhance your skills.

P.S.: There are a lot of tutorials in Internet.

Comment: The input is based on a pattern of number(s) an a description in parenthesis. There is no need for 4 different Regex patterns.

Comment: I assumed, that the input is of form: `dataPrefix dataValue`, like: "-" is date prefix, "20111213" is the date itself. "position" is date prefix, 64699 is the position itself. And all these `name value` pairs could follow in any order

Comment: This is a valid assumption, but in this case is seems that the input is specific/formatted and the source of it is not someone who is typing.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<Reading> Parser(this string[] str)
{
    List<Reading> result = new List<Reading>();
    string meterNr = "";
    Reading reading;
    foreach (string s in str)
    {
        MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(s, "\\d+|\\((.*?)\\)");
        if (mc.Count == 1)
        {
           meterNr = mc[0].Value;
           continue;
        }
        reading = new Reading()
        { 
           MeterNr = meterNr,
           Date = mc[0].Value,
           Position = mc[1].Value,
           ItemDescription = mc[2].Value.TrimStart('(').TrimEnd(')')
        };
        if (mc.Count == 4) 
            reading.Consumption = mc[3].Value;
        result.Add(reading);            
    }
    return result;
}
```